# How to change textView to a @string and raising

Tags: android, xml, string, textview

so what i am tring to do is, i am having a book like-app, and want to setup a button when click it change the textview to a string in the @string rec. but in a different way

i will put the code just a moment, lets say i have a string in @string that is NH1,NH2,NH3
i can do for button    View.setText(R.string.NH1); that will work but i want to create a counter and make it so every time clicked counter++ and want it to be like this View.setText(R.string.NH+counter); if you know what i mean so each time it clicked to goes to next @string without changing layout every time and without an array because the paragraph are very long

also if i have NH1-10 and the counter did not stop and still goes on what will i do.
if you are sill here thank you for reading.

XML(sheetpaper)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
     >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="496dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bg1"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="100" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bPrev"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="51dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:text="                      " />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvHadith"
                android:layout_width="310dp"
                android:layout_height="210dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
                android:text="@string/NH1"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bNext"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/bPrev"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/bPrev"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/tvHadith"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="                   " />

"
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Java (Nawawi)

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Nawawi extends Activity {

    private static final String NH = null;
    Button Next;
    Button Prev;
    TextView View;
    int counter = 0;
    String H=NH;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.sheetpaper);
        Next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bNext);
        Prev = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bPrev);
        View = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvHadith);

        Next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                counter++;
                View.setText(R.string.H);
            }   
}); Prev.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        counter--;
        View.setText(R.string.);
    }
});

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this by creating an XML string array, so your strings will still be referenced in resources, but you'll be able to loop through them.

Something like this, in `values/strings.xml`:

```
<string-array name="planets_array">
        <item>Mercury</item>
        <item>Venus</item>
        <item>Earth</item>
        <item>Mars</item>
</string-array>
```

And then in Activity:

```
Resources res = getResources();
final String[] planets = res.getStringArray(R.array.planets_array);

findViewById(R.id.button1).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (counter < planets.length) {
            textView.setText(planets[counter]);
            counter++;
        }
    }
});
```

Be sure to check the `counter` against arrays length, otherwise you will get an IndexOutOfBoundsException.